# Nested SQL update not working

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
UPDATE
   tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id 
SET tbl2.Field1 = 
   (SELECT TOP 1 tbl3.Field1 FROM tbl3 WHERE tbl3.FromDate<tbl1.StartDate And
    tbl3.Number=tbl2.Number ORDER BY tbl3.FromDate DESC)
```

I try to update Field1 on every row in tbl2 with the above SQL but I get the error:

> Operation must use an updateable query.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because update with join syntax varies between databases, I generally use:

```
UPDATE tbl2
    SET tbl2.Field1 =  . . .
    from tbl1
    where tbl1.id = tbl2.id
```

Comment: Don't understand - the value for Field1 is supposed to come from tbl3

Comment: If I replace the (select ...) with a value it's working as expected

Answer (score 0):

According to your description above, there's no need for updating through a join. How about:

```
UPDATE tbl2 
SET tbl2.Field1 = 
(SELECT TOP 1 tbl3.Field1 FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 AS tbl2_2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2_2.id 
                                    JOIN tbl3
 WHERE tbl3.FromDate < tbl1.StartDate
   AND tbl3.Number=tbl2.Number
 ORDER BY tbl3.FromDate DESC)
```

If tables are big, I'd consider indexing tbl3.FromDate and possible tbl2.Number.

Brian

Answer (score 0):

This is your posted SQL re-organized so it will work in an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE tbl2
SET Field1 = 
   (
      SELECT TOP 1
         tbl3.Field1
      FROM tbl1
      INNER JOIN tbl2
      ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
      INNER JOIN tbl3
      ON tbl2.Number = tbl3.Number
      WHERE 
         tbl3.FromDate<tbl1.StartDate
)
```